# How to install avconv on windows 10?

Tags: matlab, avconv

I am working on matlab R2017a. For my project, I have to install **avconv**. I have searched a lot, but I only find a useful link that is [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/avconv/). After installing it, I run **setup.exe**, add following path to environment variables that is

> C:\Program Files\AVCONV

After I execute my file, and it shows the same error that is this:

> 'avconv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file

I spent time on this, trying different solution, but found no useful help.

Comment: Did you restart matlab? Try reading the path in matlab using getenv, does it include the newly added path?

Comment: I have applied **getenv('PATH')** and I got output as **'C:\Program Files\AVCONV\AVConv_1_0_0_1\bin\Debug**. This is my required added environment variable.

Comment: You might need to add `C:\Program Files\AVCONV` to you Environment Path. https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm